# I want to select data then use update with concat to append some text (Mysql)

Tags: mysql, sql-update, concatenation

I have two schemas arkdb and kalscrosschat. Id is primary key on both.

arkdb has a table called players and fields

```
Id SteamId            PermissionGroups

1  76561197969383152  Default

2  76561197969383154  Default
```

Kalscrosschat has a table called discordsteamlinks amd fields

```
Id  SteamId           DiscordId            InviteCode

1   76561198032704712 150054663054426113   NU123

2   76561198032704714 150054663054426113   ME123
```

i have a select query.

```
    Select
        kalscrosschat.discordsteamlinks.DiscordId,
        kalscrosschat.discordsteamlinks.SteamId,
        arkdb.players.SteamId As SteamId1,
        arkdb.players.PermissionGroups
    From
        kalscrosschat.discordsteamlinks Inner Join
        arkdb.players On arkdb.players.SteamId = kalscrosschat.discordsteamlinks.SteamId
    Where
        arkdb.players.PermissionGroups Not Like '%Discord%'
```

I then need to update the arkdb.players.permissionsgroups to append Discord, to the end.

So `1 76561197969383152 Default` would become `1 76561197969383152 Default,Discord`

How do i go about this???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join the tables in the `UPDATE` statement like this:

```
UPDATE arkdb.players p
INNER JOIN kalscrosschat.discordsteamlinks d  on p.SteamId = d.SteamId
SET p.PermissionGroups = CONCAT(p.PermissionGroups, ',', 'Discord')
WHERE p.PermissionGroups NOT LIKE '%Discord%'
```

or if you have `null`s in the column `PermissionGroups`:

```
UPDATE arkdb.players p  
INNER JOIN kalscrosschat.discordsteamlinks d on p.SteamId = d.SteamId
SET p.PermissionGroups = CONCAT_WS(',', p.PermissionGroups, 'Discord')
WHERE p.PermissionGroups NOT LIKE '%Discord%' OR p.PermissionGroups IS NULL
```

Comment: Im new to all this. Im pretty sure your using the wrong DB there. I need to update arkdb.players not kalscrosschat. I need to make sure that the records I append data to have data for the steamid in both db's and do NOT include the word Discord in the arkdb.players.permissiongroups

Comment: @WNGNarny you are correct about the table that needs to be updated. See my edited answer.

Comment: It runs ok but does not update anything. Bit of sample data

8 76561198056191458 Default

should be

8 76561198056191458 Default,Discord,

Comment: In the sample data you posted there are no matching steamids. Are you sure that there are in your table?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `arkdb.players` table has `id` column as primary key, consider using the following statement with proper aliasing :

```
UPDATE arkdb.players pp
  JOIN (
        SELECT p.id, CONCAT(p.PermissionGroups,',', d.DiscordId) AS pg
          FROM kalscrosschat.discordsteamlinks AS d
          JOIN arkdb.players AS p
            ON p.SteamId = d.SteamId
         WHERE p.PermissionGroups NOT LIKE '%Discord%'
       ) dp ON  dp.id = pp.id 
   SET pp.PermissionGroups = dp.pg
```

in order to add the value of `Discord` to the end of that column's value.

Comment: Error executing query:
#42000You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'arkdb.players pp

Comment: do you have a primary key column for players table? @WNGNarny And what's the name of it(I presumed `id`)? Btw, can you share some sample data ?

Comment: No... @WNGNarny

Comment: please edit the question with sample data within the question, not as comment, and share the data seperately, individual to each table @WNGNarny

Comment: Sorry for comments. Ive updated original post and cleaned up some of the comments.

Comment: well, I think `SteamId` values **should be** equal for both tables respectively, and you mean `DiscordId` by `Discord`, don't you @WNGNarny ? Check [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=c6d0fcf338f37735be11441d9b7aea6c) out please.